# Need to open port 10000 for webmin and 21 for FTP in Centos?

Tags: centos, iptables, port

How can I open these two ports in CentOS? I have used Ubuntu before, but I never had to manually open any port.

When I enter *iptables -L*, I get output like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
[root@sachinvasudev test]#
```

Comment: Don't say it is for webmin, they will close your question because they don't like control panels.

Answer (score 3):

when you want to change it manually, here is a good tutorial:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedorta-linux-iptables-firewall-configuration-tutorial/

Otherwise you could use the programs `system-config-securitylevel` or `system-config-firewall`.

Comment: I have to agree with David. Have you tried accessing webmin or ftp?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the iptables output you posted, everything is already open.  In fact, your not blocking anything!

Answer (score 3):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

And save the changes to iptables :

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Comment: A script is not enough without a textual elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reconsider opening those ports since Webmin is notoriously full of bugs and ftp sends usernames and passwords in plain text.  Better to ssh in and tunnel through that to gain access to Webmin (or just learn to manage the server without Webmin, which in the long-term is a far better option).  For ftp, consider replacing it with sftp/scp.